# Physical url from virtual

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, routes, url-routing

On Asp.net 4 routing, how can I get the physical url from a virtual one? example:

virtual = "/Customers"
physical = "/Customers.aspx"

I want "/Customers.aspx"

Tks

Answer (score 1):

This should give you the info you need:

http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2009/Dec/21/Making-Sense-of-ASPNET-Paths

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question, I have an routed url which is "customers" I dumped the request object and there is no reference to aspx file

Comment: Not strong on routing but maybe you could store initial request object in session and retrieve it later?

Answer (score 0):

You could just use the URL Segments method (in this case it would be 1).  Segments having a delimination of "/".